# How do I instantiate a Dinero object with an amount that I have as a number?

Tags: typescript, dinero.js

I am currently designing a test that uses Cypress to add up product prices in a confirmation email and compare them with the total price. I read that you use Dinero.js in Typescript. Is that right? Is there anything better? How do I instantiate a Dinero Object with my number variable? I already have this:

```
import { Dinero, dinero, add } from 'dinero.js'
import { USD } from '@dinero.js/currencies'
import orders from '../fixtures/orders.json'

describe('Theme: Mails', () => {
  const serverId = 'TODO' // Replace SERVER_ID with an actual Mailosaur Server ID
  const testEmail = `tell-whispered@${serverId}.mailosaur.net`
  const orderTotal: Dinero = dinero({ amount: 0, currency: USD })

  it('The body of a confirmation mail shall contain strings', () => {
    cy.mailosaurGetMessage(
      serverId,
      {
        sentTo: testEmail,
      },
      { receivedAfter: new Date('2022-01-01T00:00:00Z') }
    ).then((message) => {

      orders.Products.forEach((aProduct: any) => {
        expect(message!.text!.body!.indexOf(aProduct.price) > -1).to.be.true
        // i want to have aProduct.price as Dinero object now, this fails:
        // const currentPrice = dinero({ amount: aProduct.price, currency: USD })
      })

      expect(message!.text!.body!).to.have.string(orders.OrderTotal)
      expect(orderTotal.equalsTo(Dinero({ amount: 3007400 }))).to.be.true
    })
  })
})
```

Once I've done that, how do I sum multiple objects then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself:

```
import { Dinero, dinero, add, equal } from 'dinero.js'
import { USD } from '@dinero.js/currencies'

const cents = (amount: any) => dinero({ amount, currency: USD })
const addMany = (addends: any) => addends.reduce(add)
const expectedTotal = cents(30074 * 100)
```

...

```
var prices: Dinero<number>[] = []
orders.Products.forEach((element: any) => {
  prices.push(cents(element.price * 100))
}

expect(prices.length).to.equal(60)
var total = addMany(prices)
cy.log(JSON.stringify(total))
var doesTotalEqualExpectedTotal = equal(total, expectedTotal)
expect(doesTotalEqualExpectedTotal).to.be.true
```